# Mesh gets deformed after parenting with automatic weights

Tags: rigging, armature

I've been trying to attach this character mesh to an armature using Armature Deform with Automatic Weights, but after setting the weights, the character gets its limbs shifted strangely (wrists turn up, feet come together) even though I haven't touched the pose. I'm new to character modeling and rigging, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

**Mesh After Parenting**
[image: Rigged Mesh]

**Original Mesh**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should apply armature pose as a rest pose, what i believe happens in your case is that you have corrected the armature pose in the pose mode instead of edit mode, that way you have a non neutral pose on your armature which means as soon as you apply that armature to the mesh all bones that are not in the rest pose will apply its transformations to assigned vertices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is in fact the issue! Thanks! The armature comes with its own animation I am trying to rig the mesh to, and the t-pose frame at frame 0 was not set to be its rest pose. Unfortunately for me, this means that setting the rest pose doesn't fix the rest of the animation, but thanks for helping me with this part of my problem!

Comment: You can try this: before parenting the mesh to armature, create a new animation 'action', enter pose mode, select all bones in the armature and press "alt + R" (reset rotation), then "alt + G" (reset location), then "alt + S" (reset scale). Then go back to object mode and whatever the pose the skeleton ended up in, make your mesh match that pose, and only then try to parent the mesh to the armature with automatic weights.
I'm not 100% sure it would solve it, but I'm pretty confident it would.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the transforms of the meshes in *Object > Apply> All Transforms* then re automatic weight it.